# Apache2 VirtualHost - proper silent redirect?

Tags: apache, redirect, virtualhost

hopefully a quick and simple post here.

For an example lets say I have the url "https://i.pitter.us/gwqNnGSAPuDqS.png", However when the browser loads it is sent to the actual PHP Script that is determining which server to get the image from: "https://i.pitter.us/get.php?file=gwqNnGSAPuDqS.png .

In my Apache2 VirtualHost Configuration I have this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAlias i.pitter.us
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/i
Options -Indexes
<Directory "/">
<Files  ~ "\.py*$">
  Order allow,deny
  Deny from all
</Files>
</Directory>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^i.pitter.us$
RewriteRule ^/(.*\.(png|gif|jpeg|jpg|exe|txt|zip|rar))$ https://i.pitter.us/get.php?file=$1
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php    
</VirtualHost>
```

Before further explaining what I want to attempt to do, I have searched around quite a bit on StackOverflow and have tried different methods of doing this, and still at the conclusion of I can't configure this properly by myself. I need to have the URL stay as if it was a hotlink to a direct image as listed in the example above.

Could someone provide an explanation on what flags or rules I am missing in order to properly accomplish what I am attempting?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Instead of ServerAlias, use ServerName - unless the .conf applies to additional domains/subdomains.

You don't need the RewriteCond.

You can simplify this:

```
^/(.*\.(png|gif|jpeg|jpg|exe|txt|zip|rar))$
```

to:

```
\.(png|gif|jpe?g|exe|txt|zip|rar)$
```

Also, enable the RewriteLog to help you see what Apache is doing.

```
RewriteLog /path/to/log
RewriteLogLevel Debug
```

Comment: Modifying the virtual host using your simplification causes files to point to the 404 page? I appreciate the help though.

Comment: Check your DocumentRoot and ensure get.php is there.  A good test would be to request https://i.pitter.us/get.php?file=gwqNnGSAPuDqS.png directly and see if the image is delivered.

Comment: I can confirm, get.php shows the image successfully, however the redirect rule: `RewriteRule \.(png|gif|jpe?g|exe|txt|zip|rar)$ https://i.pitter.us/get.php?file=$1` returns a 404 using the URL without get.php.

Comment: Usually HTTPS is on port 443 - is there a VirtualHost for HTTPS?

Comment: CloudFlare is performing the SSL to their servers, and HTTP to the server.

Comment: Looks like it is an nginx server? cloudflare-nginx